# jQuery get index position of an element by class from an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, class, filter

I've got multiple music players on a page and need to make an index of them to pull the position of the current player from. The issue is that the `currentPlayer` is not a child, so using `.find` or `.filter` and then `.index` will always return a value of `0` because nothing else is in the array.

So I need to find `.currentPlayer`'s index within the `player` array.

HTML (very simplified):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <article>
             <div class="player"></div>
        </article>
    </li>
    <li>
        <article>
             <div class="player currentPlayer"></div>
        </article>
    </li>
    <li>
        <article>
             <div class="player"></div>
        </article>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
var player  = $('.player'),
    current = player.filter('.currentPlayer'),
    index = current.index();
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`current.index()` will search its parent for the element. so since `current` is an only child, it's zero.

You can pass a selector to `.index`; it'll tell jQuery to search inside that for your element.

```
var player  = $('.player'),
    current = player.filter('.currentPlayer'),
    index = current.index('.player');
```

Or, you can tell jQuery to search for a specific element inside of an array:

```
var player  = $('.player'),
    current = player.filter('.currentPlayer'),
    index = player.index(current);
```

Comment: kudos for the second method- cached selectors are for winners

Comment: Yep, you already had those selectors saved, why not use 'em :-)

Answer (score 7):

You're probably looking for

```
$('div.player').index($('.currentPlayer'))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hmartiro/3Wzbd/

Answer (score 1):

```
var position = 0;
$('.player').each(function(i){
if ($(this).hasClass('currentPlayer') == true) { position = i; }
});
```