# display slide number orbit.js foundation 6 zurb

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, orbit, zurb-foundation-6

I am currently working with orbit.js slider in Foundation 6 and not seeing an option to display slide number.

Could you advice me on this or share examples please.

Thanks!

Comment: Danila, if you have successfully implemented Foundation 6 Orbit, could you show us a basic implementation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921586/cant-get-orbit-carousel-to-work-in-foundation-6-2-0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example using jQuery that will change the `innerHTML` propery of an element with the class `.slide-number` to the active slide number, and log the active slide number to the console every time the slide changes.

```
function slideNumber() {
  var $slides = $('.orbit-slide');
  var $activeSlide = $slides.filter('.is-active');
  var activeNum = $slides.index($activeSlide) + 1;
  $('.slide-number').innerHTML = activeNum;
  console.log(activeNum);
}

$('[data-orbit]').on('slidechange.zf.orbit', slideNumber);
```

**Credit:** I came up with this answer with the help of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413209/jquery-get-index-position-of-an-element-by-class-from-an-array).

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this with plain CSS.

```css
.orbit-parent {
    counter-reset: orbit-bullet-num;
}

.orbit-bullets button::after {
    content: counter(orbit-bullet-num);
    counter-increment: orbit-bullet-num;
}
```

```html
 <div class="orbit-parent">
     <div class="orbit" aria-label="Slider" data-orbit>
         <ul class="orbit-container">
         ...
         ...
         </ul>
         <nav class="orbit-bullets" aria-label="Slider Navigation">
            <button data-slide="0" class=""><span class="show-for-sr">First slide details.</span></button>
            <button data-slide="1" class=""><span class="show-for-sr">Second slide details.</span></button>
            <button data-slide="2" class="is-active"><span class="show-for-sr">Third slide details.</span><span class="show-for-sr">Current Slide</span></button>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is full jQuery code to properly working.
Also add css class "orbit-slide-number" where you want to show this on the page

```
function slideNumber() {
    var $slides = $('.orbit-slide');
    var totalItems = $('.orbit-container li').length;
    var $activeSlide = $slides.filter('.is-active');
    var activeNum = $slides.index($activeSlide) + 1;

    $('.orbit-slide-number').html(''+activeNum+'/'+totalItems+'');
}

slideNumber(); // call for every

// call for automatic slide change
$('[data-orbit]').on('slidechange.zf.orbit', slideNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who might want to use vanilla js:

```
function slideNumbers() {
  const arrows = document.getElementsByClassName("orbit-arrow");
  const target = document.getElementById("currentSlide");
  [...arrows].forEach(function(arrow) {
    arrow.addEventListener("click", function() {
      const currentSlide = document.querySelector(".is-active");
      target.textContent = Number(currentSlide.getAttribute("data-slide")) + 1;
    });
  });
}
```