# Can't get Orbit Carousel to work in Foundation 6.2.0

Tags: orbit, zurb-foundation-6

I'm been trying for the life of me to get a basic Orbit carousel to work but it just isn't happening. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I've tried various alternatives and had a look at the documentation but am getting nowhere:

Code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Orbit Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
          <ul data-orbit>
            <li>
              <div>
                <p><strong>This is item 1.</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>
                <p><strong>This is item 2.</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>
                <p><strong>This is item 3.</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>
                <p><strong>This is item 4.</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>$(document).foundation();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if you copy and paste the example from the website?

Comment: There are no 'real world' examples on the website. In fact most of the Foundation 6 documentation is lacking in displaying actual implementation. It is unfortunate.
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/orbit.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your `foundation.css` css import in the `<head>` add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/motion-ui/1.1.1/motion-ui.min.css" />
```

or use your own downloaded copy of the motion-ui style sheet.

---

**Credit:**

I found a thread on Github that mentions the need for the Motion UI CSS to be included:

[[F 6.0.4] Orbit don't work correctly #7264](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7264)

In the Foundation 6 Motion UI doc, I found the mention of the Motion UI CSS being necessary for transitions in the Orbit, Toggler and Reveal components:

[Foundation 6 Motion UI doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/motion-ui.html)

And down in the Motion UI doc there is link to the cdn:

[Foundation 6 Motion UI Installation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/motion-ui.html#installing)

Comment: Oh what the hell, you have to include another CSS file that's not included in the library?! All it says in the docs is that it "Supports Motion UI", no mention of "oh by the way, you need to install this" http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/motion-ui.html#installing

Comment: Even that didn't cover it all; I'm including the all my sass (including vendor libraries) into my `main.scss` file. Just including the `motion-ui.scss` file is not enough, you also need to include the two main mixins for the entire CSS to load: `@include motion-ui-transitions;` 
`@include motion-ui-animations;` Hopefully this saves someone else some time. https://github.com/zurb/motion-ui/blob/master/docs/installation.md